# IN OBJECT DETECTION 'model_builder' error coming that it does not have an attribute called build(JUPYTER NOTEBOOK)

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

THIS is the error(jupyter notebook):

```
AttributeError                         
in <module>

      6 configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(CONFIG_PATH)
----> 7 detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=configs['model'], is_training=True)
      8 

AttributeError: module 'model_builder' has no attribute 'build'
```

I'm USING 'Model-Builder-0.4.7' and this error is coming when i am Loading Train Model From Checkpoint

Things imported (these are correct)-

```
import os
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils
from object_detection.utils import config_util
import model_builder
```

Please help!!!

Comment: I think its fixed i just did 'import tensorflow as tf' and it was solved :)